# When do browsers reject invalid html? Especially when dynamically created

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Modern browsers routinely fix invalid html by rearranging elements in the DOM, but when you create the same html-structure with JavaScript, it remains intact. Why? This seems consistent across browsers. Is there a W3C recommendation how such cases should be handled? Under what circumstances can we expect browsers to intervene?

For examples, see the following JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/od0uwxsb/

It includes `span`-Elements in place of `td`-Elements and `table`-Elements inside `p`-nodes. In both cases browsers fix the invalid html in the initial load, but keep it intact when the structure is created dynamically.

Comment: Because HTML parsing, and DOM manipulation, are different things.

Comment: @CBroe: That's what I would have guessed as well. I was wondering, however, whether this behaviour is down to an official specification or whether this is simply "what modern browsers (currently) do".